# AudioQueueNewOutput with AudioQueueRef? always unwrapping nil

Tags: ios, swift, core-audio, audiotoolbox

I have this snippet of code

```
var queue: AudioQueueRef?
try SCoreAudioError.check(status: AudioQueueNewOutput(&dataFormat!, myAQOutputCallback, &player, nil, nil, 0, &queue),"`AudioQueueNewOutput` had an error")
```

Which, for some reason, the `AudioQueueRef?` is unwrapping its value before being sent

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

as far as I know, I need an empty reference `AudioQueueRef?` in the `AudioQueueNewOutput` function, and that reference is going to be filled with data aren't I right?

If I'm right, then why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your `AudioQueueRef` is fine, and instead `dataFormat` is nil.

Comment: you were right, now i dont know why my asbd is being nil